# Java JWS web service on CPANEL

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cpanel, whm

I need help. I developed a Java web service and it's working properly on my development environment. When I deployed it on a Virtual Private Server (VPS), it's not working and I'm having a 404 error. I installed Tomcat 7 on the server and I enabled Servlet. JSP files are working properly but the web service is not working.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: which webservice framework you are using?

Comment: I'm using javax jws framework